# Firestore updated values erasing existing ones

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

My plan is to not delete values that already exist in my array, I have this array

```
products [{

   - 0 
    productPrice : 123
    productName: 32

   - 1 
    productPrice : 432
    productName: 21
]}
```

Now, I update the price of the element 0 in my array so I get the entire array, edit the price and then I just send the arrray to the same node products, but when I do this with update I'm expecting to just touch and update the price value, but instead .update is erasing my productName field

```
suspend fun updateProductPrice(position:Int,shopId: String,price: Int,productList:MutableList<Product>): Resource<Unit> {
        productList[position].price = price
        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("shops").document(shopId).update("products",productList).await()
        return Resource.Success(Unit)
    }
```

My product data class

```
data class Products(val productPrice:Int = 0)
```

Now, I know that I don't have productName here, but I don't need to have it if the only thing in the entire array that I will update is the price, so, why my update is erasing productName if I told to just update the price value?

Also, I know that adding productName:String = "" will not erase it and leave it like it is, but my use case requires to just touch that price element and not the other ones because I have more elements in my Products data class, but if I also place them to have the entire document, it will also add those fields to the array that I don't want because it will increase the document size with defaults field values that I don't want to update

Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code updates the entire `products` field in the document, with the value you specify. Since the new value you specify for `products` contains only one item, that is what the document ends up with after this update.

If you want to retain the existing values, you'll need to:

1. Read the existing document data
2. Get the current array values from that
3. Modify the array
4. Write back the modified array as you're doing now.

Comment: Thanks a lot frank ! you are so gentle

Answer (score 2):

> but when I do this with update I'm expecting to just touch and update the price value, but instead .update is erasing my productName field

That's the expected behavior since your `productList` is defined to be of type `Product` and the class itself contains only one property, which is `productPrice`.

> Now, I know that I don't have `productName` here, but I don't need to have it if the only thing in the entire array that I will update is the price, so, why my update is erasing `productName` if I told to just update the price value?

It's erasing the `productName` because the new object that you are using for the update operation, contains only one property. So the old object (with two properties) is overwriten with the new object that contains only one property. So you didn't "tell" just to update the price, you actually told to erase the old object and add a new one with only one property.

> I know that adding productName:String = "" will not erase it and leave it like it is

Yes, that way you should go ahead.

> but my use case requires to just touch that price element and not the other ones

In that case, you should [get the entire array as a List of `Product` class objects](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-list-of-objects-122e579eae10), wich a class that contains two properties and **not** only one, make the update and write the document back.

> but if I also place them to have the entire document, it will also add those fields to the array that I don't want because it will increase the document size with defaults field values that I don't want to update

You only need to add the data that you need to use and nothing more. If you are worried about the size of the document, you can always check against the maximum 1 MiB quota using the [FirestoreDocument-Android](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreDocument-Android/tree/master/firestore-document) library.

Comment: Thanks Alex! I did what you mentioned in your article, the problem is not getting and modifying the array, the problem is updating only the desied values at my database, as you can see I get from the method parameter th arraylist itself, and I just edit the price at one elemnt of the array with position, can you elaborate how to update that document without erasing nothing? thanks for your answer its really nice and you took your time

Comment: I dont want to add more fields that are unnecesary to my document, because If I modify the data class adding one extra field (productName) if the list I'm pulling does not have that element, the update will write it with default values (this is what I dont want) because is increasing document size without a reason, since I jsut need to update the price @AlexMamo